# Ajax form does not work, security update in browser causing the issue?

Tags: ajax, security, same-origin-policy, cross-site

here's my problem, I currently have a issue with a form, when the submit button is pressed, the information are not sent to the server. A programmer friend of mine checked and told me it is a security update in browser that caused the issue.

Screencap:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3en22ryjr6idv6w/error.png

FYI, Im not a programmer, but I hope to understand more about this issue, so at least I have an idea of what is going on now. Can anyone show some resolving methods or links to tutorials to resolve it? Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to post the specific section of the code that is making the Ajax request, but the issue appears to be pretty obvious based on the log messages.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a browser security update. Its the basic same-origin-policy implemented by all the browser.

Javascript loaded from a particular can't make AJAX request to other domain until same-origin-policy is relaxed. Please read more about it

[understanding-the-web-same-origin-policy](http://blog.logicboost.com/2012/12/13/understanding-the-web-same-origin-policy-restrictions-purpose-and-workarounds/)